# How to check whether a type is string in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to go through all the properties of a type and want to check whether a property type is not a string, how can I do it ?

My class is:

```
public class MarkerInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Color { get; set; }
    public TypeId Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsGUIVisible { get; set; }

    public MarkerInfo()
    {
        Color = new byte[4]; // A, R, G, B
        IsGUIVisible = true;
    }
}
```

the code I am using to check for type is:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(MarkerInfo).GetProperties())
{               
    if (property.PropertyType is typeof(string))              
}
```

But this code is not working, any idea how to do that  ?

Answer (score 53):

```
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the following instead:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(MarkerInfo).GetProperties())
{               
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))              
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use `==` and not `is` or `is String` (leave the typeof)